# Fabric.js - Implementing shape recognition on newly created paths

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to add basic shape recognition features to a Fabric.js based project.
I currently use the path:created observer to fetch the newly created path and then pass the path representation to a function which can figure if the path creates some kind of shape or not , i'm just wondering how does the entire path is actually represented.

I could see that the path object has a path array which represents the path itself but can't quite figure how it does that, if anyone has a better idea of implementing this sort of feature, I would be more than happy to hear.

Answer (score 1):

The created path is an instance of `fabric.Path`. `fabric.Path` more or less mirrors format of [SVG <path> element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathElement) (also see [path data](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData)). `fabric.Path::render` [parses this data and renders shape](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/path.class.js#L245-435) accordingly.